# Errors from running code compiled by gcc

Tags: 18.04, compiling, gcc

So I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my (not so shiny) new thinkpad and I'm loving it, especially the new GNOME getup.

So I was looking to run some c++ code. Seems gcc is already installed by default so I try out a simple hello world program called test.cpp

I compile it: `cpp test.cpp -o test` ... works fine no errors.
I then try to run it but it says permission denied, so I do a quick `chmod u+x` and it seems to at least try to run the program. No matter what code I put in and compile, it always comes with these errors:

```
./test: line 18: namespace: command not found
./test: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test: line 22: `  typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;'
```

--Also note that there are only 7 lines of code and it gives me an error for line 18+?! Also why is it giving me errors after I compiled it?!

So I made a new account on #askubuntu and here I am now.

Comment: If your test is really c++ code, you should install and use the g++ compiler, not the gcc compiler.

Comment: oh sorry by gcc I meant the gcc compiler collection which is pre-installed on Ubuntu, to actually compile the code I used cpp which is part of gcc

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, but I can assure you that i typed the command ./test rather than ./test.cpp. @steeldriver

Answer (score 1):

`cpp` is the [C pre-processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) - it is not a compiler. Its output is a text file containing expanded macros and declarations from any files that your code has `#include`ed. When you made it executable and tried to run it, your shell made an attempt to interpret this text as shell code - and failed.

To compile your C++ file (and link into an executable) you should use `g++` instead:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

Comment: it all makes sense now, guess I mixed up